# 302 response handling sent by backend handling in Angular 7 Application

Tags: angular

I am working on a payment gateway which after success or failure the backend will automatically redirects to the corresponding merchant page.But In angular I am unable to handle those 302 responses.Suggest me how to do it?

Comment: You cannot handle 302 using javascript. 302 and most redirects are transparently handled by browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own http interceptor ([angular doc](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)). It allow you to react on each 302 code in any request.

Comment: Can you explain me more about that interceptor how should I handle them.I have done that too but it is throwing JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad.